# removing items from a list on python?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I can not figure out how to remove the empty spaces in this list.

```
list = [['1'],['2'],[],['3'],['5'],[],['7']]
```

how would I remove the empty spaces in my list on python?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension. The code below will check if an element in the given list is equal to `[]`. If it is not then it will append it to a new list.

```
lst = [['1'],['2'],[],['3'],['5'],[],['7']]
newList = [l for l in lst if l != []]
```

output

```
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['5'], ['7']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **list comprehension** to remove sublists that are empty :

```
L = [['1'],['2'],[],['3'],['5'],[],['7']]
filtered = [sublist for sublist in L if len(sublist) > 0]
print(filtered)
```

Output :

```
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['5'], ['7']]
```